# Unity Analytics: I see custom events in funnels, but not in the Event Manager?

Tags: unity, analytics

I've just started using **Unity Analytics**, and I send two custom events: *level1Started* and *level2Started*.

After 1,5 days, the first results came in:

- The **funnels are working**, so my custom events do reach Unity Analytics.
- But in **Event Manager** I can't see the mentioned events by themselves.

**4 days** already have passed, the **funnel is updated** every day, but the **Event Manager is still empty**.

Or I'm looking at the wrong page? Then where can I see the **raw number of events**?

Why?

**UPDATE:**

For some reason, it took 12 days for them to show up in the Event Manager as well. Anyone knows why?

**UPDATE AGAIN:**

**Now it's gone again. Why?**